# Sharekit remove unused services

Tags: ios, xcode, sharekit

I'm using Sharekit inside my app, the whole app is about 3 mb, but when i added Sharekit its weight is increased till 10Mb. Is there any way to remove unused services from Sharekit lib, since  i'm using only 2 services from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the way you include ShareKit so that each service you use is individually included. This is called a granular install and is described [here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Granular-install).